# Loading data into Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm new to neo4j.
I have data as a CSV file in local Windows machine,how can I import it into Community Edition of Neo4j using Windows platform.

Sample query which I'm trying:

```
LOAD CSV FROM "D:\Neo4j\try.csv"
  AS empdetails
MERGE (i:ID { id: empdetails[0]})
MERGE (m:EmpName { name: empdetails[1]})
MERGE (c:Cmpname { cname: empdetails[2]})
CREATE (m)-[:WORKS_IN]->(c)
```

My sample data looks like:

```
id empname      cmpname
1  arunprakash  LntInfotech
```

And I'm facing a problem in loading data from the above URL.
Can anyone please help me out...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Make sure you use Neo4j 2.1.0 (currently only available as a milestone release) and that you commit your transaction after the query has completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above path dnt work for me. The path which i got the result is  "file:D:\\Neo4j\\try.csv".

Answer (score 0):

I could load like FROM "file:///D:/Neo4j/try.csv"